# Adding information from polygon to raster in R?

Tags: raster, r

I would like to add information from a spatial polygon to a new raster.

```
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
xym = matrix(c(0,0,0,45,45,45,45,0),4,2,byrow=T) ## create coordinate list
p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
plot(r)
plot(sps,add=T,col="blue")
```

How do I create a new raster that assigns the numeric value of the polygon (FID) depending on if the polygon overlaps the raster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add values to the polygons see SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in sp package and for converting the polygon ids to a raster, given a fixed extent, see rasterize in the raster package. If you have polygons that occur outside the rasters extent you can play with the mask argument.

Here is a quick illustration using the op's "reproducible example" (thank you).

```
require(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
xym = matrix(c(0,0,0,45,45,45,45,0),4,2,byrow=T) ## create coordinate list
p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)

# Creates a polygon object with attributes
sps = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list(ps)), 
                            data.frame(IDS=1:length(ps)))

# Convert polygon(s) to raster, within "r" extent, using specified field in @data slot
( rp <- rasterize(sps, r, field="IDS", background=NA) )                         

par(mfrow=c(2,1))                           
  plot(r)
  plot(rp)
```